# How to stop IISExpress to rewrite / redirect

Tags: iis-express

I have checked **web.config**.
I have checked **applicationhost.config** in many locations:

- .vs/
- {user}\Documents\IISExpress\config

I have also used **appcmd list vdir** but IISExpress keeps rewriting / redirecting.

What else could I check?
Thankx

Comment: "but IISExpress keeps rewriting / redirecting" Please describe clearly what's that, as redirection can come from multiple sources (even web apps themselves can do redirection). If you cannot find any IIS configuration for redirection, then you hit something else.

Comment: When I change the project url from http://localhost:15536/ to http://localhost:15538/ the rewrite/redirect does not occur. So I assume it must be a iisexpress thing, but I cannot find the configuration, where this is configured. There are not redirection in the application. Thankx!

Comment: Clear the browser cache, as that often makes things tricky.